# Can Ubuntu touch run Linux programs?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm interested in Ubuntu Touch.

I'm wondering if it can run Linux programs like Steam or LibreOffice?
Some Android mobile users installed Ubuntu 13.04 on their devices, and they can run Linux programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr:** It's not possible to run Steam and Libreoffice currently, but it eventually might be.

The goal of Ubuntu Touch is **convergence** - the same app being able to run on different devices, like computers and phones.

While Ubuntu Touch is Linux-based, graphical programs [currently won't work on it](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/FAQ#Which_applications_do_run_on_Ubuntu_Touch.3F) unless they're written specifically to run on it. That may change in the future, however.

Valve, the owner of Steam, hasn't said anything about supporting Ubuntu Touch yet. Any Steam support will have to come from them.

[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) is open source, so you *could* port it Ubuntu Touch. That being said, it would be quite an undertaking. Again, there currently aren't any plans to do so.

As far as LibreOffice is concerned, there will be alternatives to it. It'll take a while, though, before it and Steam are ported (if they ever are).

Comment: How about wine, do they have a wine port for it?